# How to write TypeScript definition for a middleware that adds property to the response?

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, middleware, typing

I'd like to use [express-boom](https://github.com/scottcorgan/express-boom) for express with TypeScript. It lacks of typings so I'd like to write my own. Just make it compile is trivial.

This middleware decorates the `res` object with a property `boom` (derived from the [boom module](https://github.com/hapijs/boom)):

```
var express = require('express');
var boom = require('express-boom');

var app = express();

app.use(boom());

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.boom.notFound(); // Responsds with a 404 status code
});
```

But with typescript I need to cast it because neither `http.ServerResponse` and `Express.Response` have the boom property, of course:

```
return (<any>res).boom.badRequest('bla bla bla');
```

Which is the cleanest way to do it? Which are other typed middleware that are doing a similar thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's quite a few other Express middlewares you can use as examples, e.g. [Method-Override](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override), and its [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/method-override/index.d.ts).

As a more concrete example, if you want to add this .boom property to the response object, you should just need to create a type definition (express-boom.d.ts) containing:

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface Boom {
        // Add boom's properties in here
    }

    export interface Response {
        boom: Boom
    }
}
```

Comment: super, it works. just a things, and how to automatically add all the [typed method of boom](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cc3d223a946f661eff871787edeb0fcb8f0db156/boom/boom.d.ts) to the `boom` function?

Comment: Sadly, I don't think you can. You need to be able to use the Boom namespace as a type, so you can refer to it here, and I don't think that's possible, afaik. I'd love to hear if you do find a way though.

Comment: You can use the Boom namespace as a type, although that may not have been true at the time you wrote your answer. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample usage. Hope this helps someone.

Include `express-boom.d.ts` along with your applications source files.

Refer the `sample-usage.ts` in the below gist for example usage:

[Gist: Type definitions for express-boom](https://gist.github.com/sandeepsuvit/2486c99c0346db87de24539472f34451):

### `express-boom.d.ts`

```
/**
 * Type definitions for express-boom
 * Definitions by: Sandeep K Nair <https://github.com/sandeepsuvit>
 * @author: Sandeep K Nair
 */
declare namespace Express {
    interface Boom {
        // Add boom's properties in here
        wrap: (error: Error, statusCode?: number, message?: string) => BoomError;
        create: (statusCode: number, message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;

        // 4xx
        badRequest: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        unauthorized: (message?: string, scheme?: any, attributes?: any) => BoomError;
        forbidden: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        notFound: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        methodNotAllowed: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        notAcceptable: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        proxyAuthRequired: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        clientTimeout: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        conflict: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        resourceGone: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        lengthRequired: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        preconditionFailed: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        entityTooLarge: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        uriTooLong: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        unsupportedMediaType: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        rangeNotSatisfiable: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        expectationFailed: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        badData: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        tooManyRequests: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;

        // 5xx
        notImplemented: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        badGateway: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        serverTimeout: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        gatewayTimeout: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
        badImplementation: (message?: string, data?: any) => BoomError;
    }

    export interface BoomError {
        data: any;
        reformat: () => void;
        isBoom: boolean;
        isServer: boolean;
        message: string;
        output: Output;
    }

    export interface Output {
        statusCode: number;
        headers: any;
        payload: any;
    }

    export interface Response {
        boom: Boom
    }
}
```

### `sample-usage.ts`

```
export function someMiddleware(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
  // use it this way
  res.boom.forbidden("Failed to grant access to resource.");
  next();
}
```

Comment: What about return type of the middleware?